# Problem with mpiCC

Tags: mpi

I just downloaded openmpi 1.10.2 from https://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v1.10/ and installed it on my ubuntu 14.04LTS(./configure then make all install). But when I try to use mpiCC to compile a .cpp file, I get the error:

> mpiCC: error while loading shared libraries: libopen-pal.so.13: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Some people on the internet say that putting the path of the lib directory under the openmpi directory into the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environmental variable should solve the problem, but it didn't!

Also, it seems that there is no file by the name "libopen-pal.so.13" on my computer. The closest ones I could find under /usr/lib/openmpi/lib are libopen-pal.so and libopen-pal.so.4.0.5.

What should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 22):

This solved it for me:
`sudo ldconfig`

After that, I was able to run mpicc on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: thx, it worked for me

Comment: Works for me in Ubuntu 22.04, 7 years later!