# openmpi installation fails locally and on remote server

Tags: command-line, compiling, make

I tried installing version `4.0.5.tar.gz` on an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server at school but it failed following instructions here that say:

```
shell$ gunzip -c openmpi-4.0.5.tar.gz | tar xf -
shell$ cd openmpi-4.0.5
shell$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
<...lots of output...>
shell$ make all install
```

So I tried version 3.1.6 and it failed again.

The error was:

```
  make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/openmpi/amca-param-sets'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 amca-param-sets/example.conf '/usr/local/share/openmpi/amca-param-sets'
/usr/bin/install: cannot remove '/usr/local/share/openmpi/amca-param-sets/example.conf': Permission denied
Makefile:1806: recipe for target 'install-dist_amca_paramDATA' failed
make[2]: *** [install-dist_amca_paramDATA] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/T00057442/openmpi31/openmpi-3.1.6/contrib'
Makefile:1897: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/T00057442/openmpi31/openmpi-3.1.6/contrib'
Makefile:1896: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

for version 3.1.6 on the server and locally:

```
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/openmpi/amca-param-sets'
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/share/openmpi’: Permission denied
Makefile:1789: recipe for target 'install-dist_amca_paramDATA' failed
make[2]: *** [install-dist_amca_paramDATA] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/media/nobu/UbuntuFiles/Downloads/openmpi-4.0.5/contrib'
Makefile:1880: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/nobu/UbuntuFiles/Downloads/openmpi-4.0.5/contrib'
Makefile:1879: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

so both times it is `install-am`?  What is that and has anyone successfully installed openmpi or mpich?  I need it for Ray Surveyor:  http://zorino.github.io/raysurveyor-tutorial/#/42

Edit:
I run

```
base) nobu@gold3forever:~/Desktop/BioInformatics/RA/kover/ray$ mpiexec --version
mpiexec: error while loading shared libraries: libopen-rte.so.40: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

then I tried:

```
(base) nobu@gold3forever:~/Desktop/BioInformatics/RA/kover/ray$ mpirun --version
mpirun: error while loading shared libraries: libopen-rte.so.40: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Finally

```
(base) nobu@gold3forever:~/Desktop/BioInformatics/RA/kover/ray$ mpicxx --showme:version
mpicxx: error while loading shared libraries: libopen-pal.so.40: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I thought I was okay, following directions from @NOrbert in his answer but when I try to install Ray Surveyor I get

```
(base) nobu@gold3forever:~/Desktop/BioInformatics/RA/kover/ray$ make PREFIX=`pwd`/BUILD MAXKMERLENGTH=64 HAVE_LIBZ=y HAVE_LIBBZ2=y ASSERT=n;
  CXX code/application_core/ray_main.o
mpicxx: error while loading shared libraries: libopen-pal.so.40: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'code/application_core/ray_main.o' failed
make: *** [code/application_core/ray_main.o] Error 127
```

Comment: This appears to be a simple permissions issue - you are running `make install` as a non-privileged user and therefore it does not have permission to write to the `/usr/local/share/` directory

Comment: @steeldriver I will try this. `sudo make install all` or is it `sudo make install`?

Comment: First `make all`; if that succeeds you can then proceed to `sudo make install`

Comment: command: `ompi_info` returns
`ompi_info: error while loading shared libraries: libmpi.so.40: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to compile OpenMPI by yourself.

This package [is presented](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/openmpi) in Ubuntu repositories.

Simply install it with:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get install libopenmpi-dev
```

and then continue with compilation of only Ray Surveyor.

Comment: I got `libopenmpi-dev is already the newest version (2.1.1-8).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 70 not upgraded.` so I guess it is installed.  I ran instructions here before trying any of the above: https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/openmpi-bin

Comment: When I tried to install Ray Surveyor following instructions here: https://github.com/zorino/RaySurveyor-Tutorial, I get ```(base) nobu@gold3forever:~/Desktop/BioInformatics/RA/kover/ray$ make PREFIX=`pwd`/BUILD MAXKMERLENGTH=64 HAVE_LIBZ=y HAVE_LIBBZ2=y ASSERT=n;
  CXX code/application_core/ray_main.o
mpicxx: error while loading shared libraries: libopen-pal.so.40: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'code/application_core/ray_main.o' failed
make: *** [code/application_core/ray_main.o] Error 127```

Comment: Actually running `sudo ldconfig` I found here: https://askubuntu.com/a/784120/1118094 and now that last step is executing.

Answer (score 1):

Per the comment above, `sudo ldconfig` I read on that link after the steps provided by @NOrbert.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while trying to install OpenMPI 4.0.0 in Ubuntu 18.04. I wanted this particular version for another library. I solved this by running `sudo make all install` instead of `make all install`. You can notice this error in the
error logs in the question too (`Permission denied`).